# Distance matrix inside a neural net

Tags: neural-networks, coordinate-transformation

So what I would like to do is to create a NetGraph that takes in an $n\times 3$ (with $n$ varying in length) list of 3D coordinates as an input and creates an $n \times n$ distance matrix or an $\frac{n (n-1)}{2} $ list of distances between these points. I would run this net for two lists of 3D coordinates and feed the results into a MeanSquaredLossLayer. This would allow the neural net to learn to reproduce an arrangement of points with the loss invariant with respect to translations and rotations in 3D. However, I only have vague ideas what modules I should use. Maybe NetMapOperators and NetMapThreadOperators? If these, then how? Thank you for the answer in forward!

**Edit**: Normally, without the NN framework I would do the following to obtain the pairwise distances in a list and then calculate the loss:

```
distances[x_] := 
 Flatten@Table[
   Table[Norm[x[[i]] - x[[j]]], {i, 1, j-1}], {j, 1, Length@x}]
coordList1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}}; (*Small examples*)
coordList2 = {{1, 5, 3}, {2, 3, 10}, {11, 4, 5}};
loss = Sqrt@
  Mean[#^2 & /@ (distances[coordList1] - distances[coordList2])]
```

Comment: Do you think you could add some code to your question, explaining how you would do some of your operation normally (ie, without the NN framework)? That way, a potential answerer can be sure of the veracity of their solution.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, could you also add a small version of `coordList1` and `coordList2`? Thanks!